# Replacing multiple characters at once

Tags: python, string, replace, str-replace

Is there any way to replace multiple characters in a string at once, so that instead of doing:

```py
"foo_faa:fee,fii".replace("_", "").replace(":", "").replace(",", "")
```

just something like (with `str.replace()`)

```py
"foo_faa:fee,fii".replace(["_", ":", ","], "")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An option that requires no looping or regular expressions is [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```py
>>> "foo_faa:fee,fii".translate(str.maketrans('', '', "_:,"))
"foofaafeefii"
```

Note that for Python 2, the API is [slightly different](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: Good one! I keep forgetting about `.translate` and `.maketrans`. This is about 2.3x faster than my regexp answer on my box (when both the translation table and the regexp are precomputed).

Comment: Note this will not work for unicode characters like ‘ ’. For that using @AKX's code with regex will work.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly with `replace`, but you can build a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with a character class for those characters and substitute all of them at once. This is likely to be more efficient than a loop, too.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"[_:,]+", "", "foo_faa:fee,fii")
'foofaafeefii'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a loop:

```
replace_list = ["_", ":", ","]
my_str = "foo_faa:fee,fii"
for i in replace_list:
    my_str = my_str.replace(i, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to replace the characters by "", you could try:

```
''.join(c for c in "foo_faa:fee,fii" if c not in ['_',':',','])
```

Or alternatively using [string.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) (with Python 2):

```
"foo_faa:fee,fii".translate(None,"_:,")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex for such kind of operations

```py
import re

s = "foo_faa:fee,fii"

print(re.sub("_*|:*|,*", "", s))
```